# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in React Enzyme Testing

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I m testing some react components, a basic tests suite just to know if a component is rendering and their child's.

```
1) Test suite Stepper Stepper:
  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**
   at Stepper.render (D:/SAPADS/build/operation/common/stepper/Stepper.jsx:7:18)
   at D:\SAPADS\build\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:796:21
   at measureLifeCyclePerf (D:\SAPADS\build\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:75:12)
   at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (D:\SAPADS\build\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:795:25)
   at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (D:\SAPADS\build\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:822:32)
   at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (D:\SAPADS\build\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:362:30)
   at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (D:\SAPADS\build\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:258:21)
   at Object.mountComponent (D:\SAPADS\build\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
   at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (D:\SAPADS\build\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:371:34)
```

Getting error while running test case using Enzyme +Mocha.Pls help me out with this.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to get the length of is undefined. Debug to find out why.

Comment: You haven't posted any code so it wouldn't be possible for anyone to tell you specifically what's wrong. I also second the suggestion posed by @Carcigenicate.

Comment: @Samo Debugging is always the answer lol. But seriously. As soon as you see "Cannot read property * of undefined", you should probably start booting up your debugger.